# Why does this function cause a Maximum recusion error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very simple function in python that I made while using codecademy.com. The code passed the exercise but it does cause a maximum recursion error and I do not understand why. This is what I have:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return double_list(x)

print double_list(n)
```

Comment: Your recursive function don't have any breaking condition.

Comment: This function is obviously never ending. I mean, think a little more about this. You don't ever exit from it, just keep going with the same list over and over again.

Comment: As a style note, `return x` is preferred to `return(x)`. Since one of the first goals of Python is that it should be readable, little things matter. See the [PEP8 Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in your `double_list` you are calling `double_list` again?

```
return double_list(x)
```

That will cause you to enter the endless loop unless you set a condition in which it should break upon.

OP already solved it, and this is his solution:

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
    return x

print double_list(n)
```

Comment: thank you, I just changed it to `return (x)` and that fixed it.

Comment: Hehe, sometimes you need to say something out loud before you realize what you've done wrong. Don't forget to mark an answer as correct :)

Comment: I will mark it correct as soon as I can, the mandated 13 minutes have not passed yet. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a base case. Every recursive function should have a base case. It keeps calling itself and hence reaches the max depth.

The line

```
return double_list(x)
```

calls the same function again and again.

Comment: thank you @sukrit I changed it to return (x) and that solved it.